# Is there any repository to make telebot markup button pageable

Tags: python, github, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm using https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI, and i have to make markup buttons pageable. Are there any repositories, that help solve my problem? Or should i do this myself? And if yes, i would be glad if you give me some advices, how to realise it
[image: markup]

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you can create some inline keyboard and than using the method `edit_message_reply_markup` here some code:

```
from telebot import TeleBot
from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup as InlKeyMake
from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardButton as InlKeyBut

TOKEN = 'TOKEN'
bot = TeleBot(TOKEN)

def keyTemplate(row):
    key = InlKeyMake()
    key.row_width = row
    return key

# creating some keyboard
def page1():
    key = keyTemplate(2)
    key.add(
    InlKeyBut('But1', callback_data='1'),
    InlKeyBut('But2', callback_data='1'),
    InlKeyBut('New page', callback_data='page2')
    )
    return key
    
def page2():
    key = keyTemplate(3)
    key.add(
    InlKeyBut('But3', callback_data='3'),
    InlKeyBut('But4', callback_data='4'),
    InlKeyBut('New page', callback_data='page3')
    )
    return key
    
def page3():
    key = keyTemplate(2)
    key.add(
    InlKeyBut('But5', callback_data='5'),
    InlKeyBut('But6', callback_data='6'),
    InlKeyBut('Start page', callback_data='page1')
    )
    return key

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(msg):
    testo = '''Menu'''
    key = page1()
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, testo, reply_markup=key)
    
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'page1')
def page1go(call):
    key = page1()
    bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.from_user.id, call.message.id, reply_markup=key)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'page2')
def page2go(call):
    key = page2()
    bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.from_user.id, call.message.id, reply_markup=key)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'page3')
def page3go(call):
    key = page3()
    bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.from_user.id, call.message.id, reply_markup=key)

bot.remove_webhook()
bot.polling()
```